# React Check the render method of `Route`

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router, transition, react-transition-group

I'm going crazy. I'm building some examples with the aim to learn `React.js`.  Actually I crashed against the TRANSITIONGROUP + ROUTER.
I can compile without problems, but then I get the following error:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
> or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You
> likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in,
> or you might have mixed up default and named imports. Check the render
> method of `Route`.

In particular, it signs with red the line with the render method in `Index.js`

```js
    const root = document.getElementById('root')
    if (root !== null) {
      ReactDOM.render(<App /> , root)
    }
```

and it gives me the suspicion that could be a problem inside the `App.js`

```js
    ...
    <Route path="/" render={(props) => <AppRoutes {...props} />} />
    ...
```

Inside AppRoutes I defined all the Transition logic

```js
    <TransitionGroup>
        <Transition
          key={window.location.pathname}
          timeout={500}
          mountOnEnter={true}
          unmountOnExit={true}
        >
          {animation => (
            <Switch location={this.props.location}>
              <Route
                exact
                path="/"
                render={(props) => <Home {...props} animation={animation} />}
              />
              <Route
                path="/component1/"
                render={(props) => <Component1 {...props} animation={animation} />}
              />
              <Route
                path="/component2/"
                render={(props) => <Component2 {...props} animation={animation} />}
              />
            </Switch>
          )}
        </Transition>
      </TransitionGroup>
```

Then inside single components, I want to get the transition state and apply my favorite animations.

In all cases I use this for imports:

```js
    import mycomponent from "mycomponent-path";
```

and for exports from inside components:

```js
    export default mycomponent
```

inside components, I use this to extend react component:

```js
    class mycomponent extends Component
```

I spent days searching and experimenting with zero results.
The code in the public github repo:
https://github.com/acidinucleici/lezioni-react/tree/master/app04

I hope in the proper suggestion to make router and transition work :)

Comment: Hi how are you `import`ing or `require`ing things like `ReactDOM` and also how are you exporting your `App`? as mixing import and require may be messing with you. also `export default App` will be different to `export App` for example

Comment: hello! I added some lines in the post with the arguments you suggested. Thank you for your interest!